# How to inspect what is being passed to the filter() function

Tags: python

How can I verify the 'context' of a `filter` statement (normally I would just use a print in a function)? For example:

```
data=[{'Name':'Greg', 'Age': 10}, {'Name': 'Sarah', 'Age': 20}]
filter(lambda item: item['Name'] == 'Greg', data)
# [{'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Greg'}]
```

Comment: `_ = filter(func, data)` `def func(x): print x, type(x)` -- something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing it a lambda, define a function that has the print statement and filter using that.

```
data=[{'Name':'Greg', 'Age': 10}, {'Name': 'Sarah', 'Age': 20}]


def my_filter(item):
    print(f'from inside filter: {item}')
    return item['Name'] == 'Greg'


print(list(filter(my_filter, data)))
```

Comment: thanks, why doesn't a lambda allow a `print` statement in it? Something like: `filter(lambda item: print(item), data)`

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense for a `lambda` function to have those kinds of side-effects, but it doesn't disallow it. You can use a print statement in a lambda, but of course it only returns `None` like a regular print statement would.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 python doesn't allow *any* statements, only simply expressions. Note, `print` is *not* a statement. You *could* have done something like `lambda item: print(item) or item["Name"] == "Greg"` or various other tricks... but usually it's cleaner to write a full funtion definition

Comment: @Grismar `print` is not a statement in Python 3. It is just a function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct - I'd not recommend it, but it works, as `None` evaluates to `False` and causes the second clause of the `or` to get evaluated and that ends up being the result.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga calling the `print()` function is still a "print statement" for all intents and purpose - I don't think pedantry around the narrow semantics of 'statement' are helpful (nor specifically meaningful in Python); strictly speaking, calling the `print()` function is an expression statement.

Comment: @Grismar um, it is absolutely relevant here, because indeed, you *cannot* use statements in `lambda` expressions, only simple expressions

Comment: I think you know full well I already indicated you're right - and as I said, a call to `print()` being an expression statement is exactly why it's allowed. I'm also not saying it's irrelevant, it's just not very helpful to get into the semantics here. @samuelbrody1249 was asking why lambda doesn't allow a print statement in it - it allows it because it is an expression, a call to a function with an assignable result. `print` being a proper separate statement in the past is Python history that doesn't really help understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to claim that this is good practice, but for very quick debugging, you can use a tuple inside the `lambda` to shimmy a call to `print` in:

```
data=[{'Name':'Greg', 'Age': 10}, {'Name': 'Sarah', 'Age': 20}]
print(*filter(lambda item: (print(item), item['Name'] == 'Greg')[1], data))

{'Name': 'Greg', 'Age': 10}
{'Name': 'Sarah', 'Age': 20}
{'Name': 'Greg', 'Age': 10}
```

`lambda`s expects a single expression that will eventually be returned. If you want to add in "sequencing" of operations, you need to get a bit creative (although I don't recommend it for real, lasting code).

---

@juanpa.arrivillaga's idea is cleaner than mine:

```
lambda item: print(item) or item["Name"] == "Greg"
```

But it's the same idea. You need to put the `print` inside in such a way that the internal expression will evaluate in the end to `item["Name"] == "Greg"`. I used the evaluation/indexing of a sequence to do that, while they used the behavior of `or`.

Comment: When using this type of syntax and using the `lambda`, I'd favour the solution @juan.arrivillaga suggested below my answer: `lambda item: print(item) or item["Name"] == "Greg"`

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I suppose that does do away with the need for bracketing and indexing. When I've used this previously in similar cases, I didn't think about using `or` to sequence.